# Rest request not working when device time is ahead

Tags: c#, rest, rest-client

I'm using a ResClient request to get a device's status from a URL, but if the device has the time ahead from the server, it doesn't bring up the new status.

Example: a camera that has the clock ahead of time, when I request the content, does not bring up-to-date information, but if it's on time or late it brings the infos.

Follow how the code is:

```
public void GetStatusDevice(Device obj)
   
var client = new RestClient("http://" + obj.Address + "/stw-cgi/eventstatus.cgi?msubmenu=eventstatus&action=check");
client.Timeout = 5000;

var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);

request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(obj.User, obj.Password);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

Is there a way to synchronize this time?

Comment: This is not answerable in this form. Whether there is an admin endpoint through which you can set the camera's time is completely up to the camera vendor, model, maybe even version of that model. You need to find out if that specific camera can do it. Maybe it can even check against a time server.

Comment: There is no common solution. It depends on the (REST) API of your device. There may be something to synchronize/set the clock. You need to look up the documentation of your device.

Comment: As a workaround (if you are out of options) you could of course request with a timestamp set to DateTime.MaxValue ... **BUT** if this is anywhere near something "security camera"ish, then you need to have correct timestamps, anyway.

Comment: Your code does not include anything time related. That said, it's hard to understand why the time diff should be a problem? If you get some json response that includes the time, you may be able to "correct" it but we can't see the response so with the given information there's no chance to help you.